# Ao salvar arquivo na pasta do servidor fica pedindo acesso root

Tags: linux, nginx

Pesquisei sobre meu problema e só encontrei soluções para host ( nenhuma se apresentou aplicável ao servidor local ), alguém sabe como eu desativo essa parada pedir a senha do root toda vez que eu salvo uma alteração no arquivo com extensão *.php* ? ( tentei `chmod` na pasta mas não funcionou )

**Nginx** 1.4.6

**Php** 5.5.9

**Ubuntu** 14.04.1 ( Backbox )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não tem haver com o Nginx, na verdade editar o arquivo na máquina não tem haver com servidores.

O problema de pedir "senha" é que a pasta que esta os scripts php estão não pertencem ao seu usuário do linux, isso é um problema do seu entendimento sobre linux.

O linux não é igual a Windows, você precisa primeiramente entender o que são grupos, usuário e permissões, mas não vou entrar em detalhes

A solução rápida é trocar a pasta aonde ficam os arquivos mudando no `nginx.conf`, procure por algo assim `root   /var/www` (ou semelhante) e ajuste para uma pasta aonde tenha acesso do usuário por exemplo, na pasta `/home/usuario` crie uma pasta chamada `/home/usuario/www` e edite o `root`, ficará algo semelhante a isto:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    root   /home/usuario/www;
```

Reinicie o Nginx após salvar as mudanças do `nginx.conf`

Agora passe a escrever os seus scripts dentro de `/home/usuario/www`

Comment: Vlw, migruei faz pouco tempo ... tô focando na programação por enquanto.